# Order each element of each group within an ObservableCollection<>

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a `ObservableCollection<>` with some groups in it.

Each group has some elements.
I wish I could reverse every element within the group, in descending `DateTime` order, while currently they are in ascending order.

I tried with this code, but the orders of the groups are simply reversed, not the elements within it:

UPDATE:

```
  public class Group : ObservableCollection<Diary>
        {
                public string Name { get; private set; }
    
                public Group(string name, ObservableCollection<Diary> icon) : base(icon)
                {
                    Name = name;                    
                }
         }

public ObservableCollection<Group> Obj { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<Group>();
        ....
Group group = new Group("", new ObservableCollection<Group>());
```

UPDATE:

```
Obj.Add(group);
group.Add(element);
group.Add(element2);
group.Reverse()
```

Comment: you need to sort each Group in the collection, not the overall collection

Comment: I have updated the code, but it seems that the elements are not reversed either

Comment: if you read the docs `Reverse` **returns** the modified list, it does not change the existing list

Answer (score 0):

> Each group has some elements. I wish I could reverse every element within the group, in descending DateTime order, while currently they are in ascending order.

I do one sample to order every group element by linq, you can take a look:

```
 public class groupinfo:List<personinfo>
{
    public string heading { get; set; }
    public List<personinfo> persons =>this; 
}

public class personinfo
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime time { get; set; }    
}

 private void btn2_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<groupinfo> groups = new ObservableCollection<groupinfo>();
        var group1 = new groupinfo()
         {
        new personinfo(){name="Sampson",time=new DateTime(2018,1,1) },
        new personinfo() { name = "Swift", time = new DateTime(2019, 2, 1) },
        new personinfo() { name = "Smith", time = new DateTime(2016, 3, 1) }

        };
        group1.heading = "S";


        var group2 = new groupinfo()
        {
            new personinfo(){name="Doe",time=new DateTime(2018,4,1) },
        new personinfo() { name = "Dark", time = new DateTime(2019, 5, 1) },
        new personinfo() { name = "Dareee", time = new DateTime(2012, 6, 1) }
        };
        group2.heading = "D";
        groups.Add(group1);
        groups.Add(group2);

        var subsTopics = (groups.SelectMany(t => t.persons, (heading, person) => new { heading
            .heading, person.name, person.time })).OrderByDescending(s=>s.time);

        var list = subsTopics.GroupBy(item => item.heading)
 .Select(group => new { Heading = group.Key, persons = group.ToList() })
 .ToList();
    }
}
```

The list will return some group value, that order by time.

Comment: I've put my Group class in the code, but I can't adapt your example to my case

Comment: @trecchino Your Diary class is equivalent to my personinfo class, just using Diary class to replace my personinfo class. then try again.